# awk -i inplace causes file to be empty

Tags: linux, awk, csv

```
168,1331122362,412482,,111,,3654
```

I have the above csv, the second column being a timestamp. I need to convert that timestamp to datetime format which i'm using the following awk statement:

```
awk -i inplace -F"," '{OFS=","; $2=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", $2);}' file.csv
```

If I remove the inplace option and add a 'print$0' it works as I expect it to work but when doing it with the inplace option it just empties my csv file. I have been looking around and haven't found anyone with similar problems so i'm assuming there is something wrong with my statement but I can't figure out what it is. Probably since i'm not familiar with awk/sed at all.

Answer (score 4):

When using `-i inplace` with GNU `awk`, you will do in-place editing of the given file.  It is the output of the `awk` program that is written back into the file.  If your `awk` program does not output anything, the file will be emptied (this is also how `sed -i` works with GNU `sed`).

You should therefore use

```
awk -i inplace -F ',' '{ OFS=","; $2 = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", $2); print }' file.csv
```

or, to avoid setting `OFS` for each input line,

```
awk -i inplace -F ',' -v OFS=',' '{ $2 = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", $2); print }' file.csv
```

or, shorter,

```
awk -i inplace -F ',' -v OFS=',' '{ $2 = strftime("%F %T", $2) }; 1' file.csv
```

Comment: Beware [using gawk -i inplace like that introduces a security vulnerability](/q/749645) unless you modify `$AWKPATH` not to include `.` or make sure you run that command from within a working directory where nobody could create a file called `inplace` or `inplace.awk`.